# Show new installed software in Eclipse installation history

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse provide a way, through Help → About Eclipse Platform… → Installation Details → Installation History Tab, to show the plugins installation history. But, this view doen't show the differences between an installation date and another one. Is there a mean to get those differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show differences between one installation date and another one, do the following:

1. select an installation date,
2. go to the lower pane and do a select all (Ctrl+A),
3. select another installation date and you will see plugins that are not present in the first date unselected in the lower pane.